# How to specify loading="lazy" on iframe around VF page

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I want to use the new `loading="lazy"` attribute on iframes generated by Lightning to wrap Visualforce pages (including when I use `lightning:container`, or use App Builder's built-in Visualforce component). Can I do that, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible today. Lazy loading still isn't even [supported on many browsers (30%+)](https://caniuse.com/#search=lazy%20loading%20via%20attribute%20for%20images) (future visitors: click the link to see the current support). That said, it's not clear that this would even be helpful for the majority of Salesforce content, because the framework already lazy loads almost everything. For example, if you want to lazy load a Visualforce page in a Record Home Page, place it on a separate tab. Until the user clicks on the tab, it won't load the Visualforce page at all. In your own apps, you can do this by using aura:if, wrapping all the content in a scrollable div, and use the onscroll event to determine when to render the content.